# Passing in an unknown number of "geom_text"s to ggplot as function parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to wrap chart creation in my own function that ultimately creates a ggplot object.  This is to reduce code repetition.  Because various charts may have different requirements, there are a few parameters.

One variation between different charts may be displaying one or more `geom_text` sets.  I had naively thought that because the `+` operator is overloaded by ggplot, I may be able to call `sum()` on a list of `geom_text` objects as follows:

```
outputPlot <- basePlot +
  geomBar +
  sum(geomTextList) +
  titles +
  theme +
  yScale +
  plotFill +
  if (coordFlip) { coord_flip() } else { NULL }
```

However, this returns `Error in sum(geomTextList) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument`.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I might be able to achieve this, or am I just shooting for the moon?  It also ultimately extends to having a list of `geom_bar` as well if required...

Comment: with a rep of 322 you should know better than to post on here w/out giving a good `dput`

Comment: Can do, but honestly was more expecting answers along the line of "Not possible, not designed that way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `sum`: ggplot2 can deal with lists of layers so the following should work:

```
baseplot + geomBar + geomtextList + …
```

Comment: Excellent, this works.  Thanks for such a simple solution.